# Menu with anchor link javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found the jquery code with the anchor in the link.

```
jQuery (document) .ready (function () {
    jQuery ("a"). on ('click', function (event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault ();
            var hash = this.hash;
            jQuery ('html, body'). animate ({scrollTop: jQuery(hash).offset ().top}, 800, function () {
              window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My menu works on anchors as one page, but I have another link there which directs to an additional subpage from which after clicking the link with an anchor I had to use a slash / to return to a single page with anchor links.
I would like that in the address bar of the page you can not see the anchor link only the main page address itself, but that the link would be directed to the appropriate part on the page with the anchor.

My menu:

```
<ul id = "categories" class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li><a href="/#anchor1">Anchor 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="/#anchor2">Anchor 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="/#anchor3">Anchor 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="new_page.html">New page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Address bar in the browser:

```
http://example.com/#anchor1
```

I would like to have the link moved to the anchor site after clicking on the anchor menu but hid the name of the anchor in the address:

```
http://example.com/
```

I am asking for help how to do it?

Comment: `if (this.hash! == "") {` need to be `if (this.hash !== "") {`

Comment: I have as you wrote, there were gaps during pasting ...

Comment: remove this:- `window.location.hash = hash;` and code will work

Comment: ok, it works great, but can I do it so that I do not have to use a slash / in the link to get a link from the other subpage and bring up the appropriate anchor position?

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: just remove `/` from the anchors

Comment: when I click on the link new_page.html I have the same menu there and when I click on the anchor it does not work without a slash, so I had to add it but in this case the name anchor # anchor1 still appears in the address bar

Comment: as I remove from the link / on another page it will not take me to the homepage of a single page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You need to remove this line:-

```
window.location.hash = hash;
```

From your code as it add the hash part to the URL.

Code need to be:-

```
<script>
jQuery (document) .ready (function () {
  jQuery ("a"). on ('click', function (event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault ();
      var hash = this.hash;
      jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery(hash).offset ().top}, 800);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, everything works great, and with this slash it will probably have to stay like that. The point is that after switching from one side to another with anchors, the anchor # address will be shown.
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: @AndreKesell  glad to help you